# How to read multiple images in python

Tags: python, image, imread

I want read 100 colour images and use them for further processing. Suppose one image size is 256x 256 by reading it in python openCV its size is (256,256,3). I now want to read 100 images and after reading I have to get the size as (100,256,256,3).

Comment: Why not just read all the individual images and stack them all up in a separate list?

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what does not work?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, supposing that your images are named like 0.png to 99.png:

```
import numpy as np

result=np.empty((100,256,256,3))
for i in range (100):
    result[i,:,:,:] = cv2.imread('{}.png'.format(i),1)
```

Comment: This answer is very nice because it doesn't allocate memory twice. However, you might want to set `dtype='uint8'` or `dtype='float32'` argument in the call to `np.empty()` or it will default to `dtype='float64'` which is usually not what you want when working with images.

Answer (score 1):

```
## your image names
#fnames = sorted(glob.glob("images/*.png"))

## read and stack 
img = np.stack([cv2.imread(fname) for fname in fnames])
```